# Displaying Photos in a ListView, how to get adapter to preload before users can see the list?

Tags: android

I need to display a number of photos in a list view which are pulled from urls in a list view.  Unfortunately there is some variance in the download time.  The actual downloading is being done in the adapter for the ListView.  these downloads are runOnUIThread.  (Yes, i know this is horrible design).  So whats happening is the images are being displayed when the download completes, which is causing the images to show up slowly and in a bit of disorder, although I am caching them.

I intent to rewrite the logic, but in the meantime, I would like to know to get the adapter to take action before the photos actually need to be displayed.  In other words I want to run the adapter before I actually intend to display the list to the user.  How can I do this?  I want this downloading to take place before the user ever sees the list.

In other words I need the below method in the adapter to run before the list is ever visible to the user:

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
 {
     // Inside here I am requesting the photo bitmap from url and setting to ImageView.
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Option 1: Pre-load in the adapter's constructor

In the adapter's constructor, iterate through collection's list and send the images to your image downloader to start downloading. You could just start the first 5-10, or up to about 50. If your users are likely to be on mobile phones, be nice to their bandwidth speed/cost and cap your pre-loading to something 20.

```java
/** Constructor of MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> */
public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
  super(context, 0, items);

  int limit = Math.min(10, items.size());
  for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    // don't fetch by position if `items` doesn't support random access
    AsyncImageLoader.prefetchImage(items.get(i).getImageUrl());
  }
}
```

-*and/or*-

#### Option 2: When loading a row, pre-load the next couple rows

In the adapter's getView, pre-load the images of the next couple items; e.g.

```java
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  int limit = Math.min(position + 4, getCount());
  for (int i = position; i < limit; i++) {
    AsyncImageLoader.prefetchImage(getItem(i).getImageUrl());
  }
}
```

Comment: How do I update the view when the fetched image is for the currently visible list item? Just call notifyDataSetChanged()?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you have `getAdapter` and `setAdapter` interfaces in your list view. The better idea in your case is to create adapter beforehand (create your own `BaseAdapter`) and tell it to start downloading images.
When you decide to show your listview - just call `setAdapter` and pass your adapter.

BTW, do not forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` from your adapter whenever you have new data. Also please note that all data update should happen in ui thread ;)

This is a simplest solution for your design :). Let me know you are interested in other options.

Comment: Thanks.  Lets say that I need 10 ImageViews prepopulated, out of say 50.  Don't need the others yet because they are not showing.  How would I get adapter to do its magic before the list actually needs to be drawn?

Comment: I've updated my question to show where the image download request is coming from. My question is really how to I get this method to run before the list is actually being requested for showing?

Comment: Oh, now I see what do you mean... As far as I know, there is no possibility to retrieve elements on demand using ListView adapter. I have my own implementation for this (extended ListView class). If you want - I can share it - it definitely should help. Just let me know. I don;t want to post entire source here since it is quite massive and I don't have time for stripping it :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use [picasso library for android](http://square.github.io/picasso/). This is a good library for image downloading. You can preload images in your adapter using this code.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  // Create your view here

  int lastImagePosition = Math.min(position + 4, getCount());

  for (int i = position + 1; i < lastImagePosition; ++i) {
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(getItem(i)); //getItem() - if your adapter data are image urls
  }

  return createdView;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Frescolib is the best solution for images in listview. If you just want to download an image and display it, Fresco will show a placeholder until it comes.
http://frescolib.org/docs/getting-started.html#_

Have a look how easy to implement.

In your XML, add a custom namespace to the top-level element

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
```

Then add the SimpleDraweeView to the layout

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
    android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/my_drawable"
  />
```

To show an image, you need only do this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/fresco/gh-pages/static/fresco-logo.png");
SimpleDraweeView draweeView = (SimpleDraweeView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
draweeView.setImageURI(uri);
```

and Fresco does the rest.

The placeholder is shown until the image is ready. The image will be downloaded, cached, displayed, and cleared from memory when your view goes off-screen.

Comment: The question ask for preload not only load.